# Scripts using functions already defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a script that asks users for two numbers to use as maximums for a times table and then draws the table using the two functions that I have defined already.  However, I don't know how to tie everything together to accomplish this.  Here is what I have:

```
print("What is the maximum value for the first factor?")
number1 = input()
print("What is the maximun value for the second factor?")
number2 = input()
print("Here is your times table:")
def times_table(times,factor):
    """takes two positive integers and returns a list of lists

    int, int -> list of lists"""
    table = [[0]*(factor+1)]
    for i in range(1,times+1):
        table.append(list(range(0,i*factor+1,i)))
    return table  


def print_table(listx):
    """takes a list of lists of numbers and displays them on the screen

    list of numbers -> numbers"""
    for x in listx:
        for y in x:
            print('{0:<10}'.format(y), end='')
        print()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that you must do.  First you must call the functions that you defined.  Second you are getting a string returned from the input function and you will need to convert that to an integer in order to using it as your code is using it.

There are a couple of other things that would be useful to do.  The input function is designed to print the prompt for you, so rather than using a print followed by the input(), just use the input with the argument.  Then it is easier to read if you define all of your functions first and then have the executed code follow.  You can have statements that will execute directly scattered throughout your code, but that makes it hard to follow.

```
def times_table(times,factor):
    """takes two positive integers and returns a list of lists

    int, int -> list of lists"""
    table = [[0]*(factor+1)]
    for i in range(1,times+1):
        table.append(list(range(0,i*factor+1,i)))
    return table  


def print_table(listx):
    """takes a list of lists of numbers and displays them on the screen

    list of numbers -> numbers"""
    for x in listx:
        for y in x:
            print('{0:<10}'.format(y), end='')
        print()

number1 = int(input("What is the maximum value for the first factor?"))
number2 = int(input("What is the maximun value for the second factor?"))
print("Here is your times table:")
table = times_table(number1, number2)
print_table(table)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `number1` and `number2` will be provided as arguments to `times_table()`, you're just missing two function calls:

```
# Calls times_table function providing number1 and number2 as arguments
# And assigns the returned variable to my_list
my_list = times_table(number1,number2)
# Call print_table function providing the list created in times_table function
print_table(my_list)
```

Comment: does this go at the end of the script?

Comment: Yes, after function definition